# Control stargazer table output in combination with mathpazo and siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, sweave, knitr, mathpazo

I like the idea to control all my numeric outputs with the smallest number possible of packages.

I use `mathpazo` to control my fonts and `siunitx` to control formatting. Yet when I knit a LaTeX table with the R package `stargazer` I lost control of formatting and when I use the option align also of font style.

Please consider the following MWE

```
% Sweave document    
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true,
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=2,
  round-minimum = 0.01}

\begin{document}


134.232343 format as \num{134.232343}

250000 format as \num{250000}

0.0000001 format as \num{0.0000001}

<<lm, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
require(stargazer)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
stargazer(lm(x~y),
          align=TRUE)

stargazer(lm(x~y))
@

\end{document}
```

which produces (as expected) the following inline number formatting

[image]

a first table which neither applies `mathpazo` font styling in the first two rows (because of the `align`option) nor enforce `siunitx` settings

[image]

and a second table which applies `mathpazo` consistently across all rows but not `siunitx` settings

[image]

I guess the problem derives from different settings of the tabular environment. In the first case

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} }
```

and in the second case

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc}
```

I am not sure how to control that through `stargazer` options. What I am trying to obtain is to control table output via `siunitx` setting and avoid loosing `mathpazo` when using the option `align`. Is that possible?